# Javascript file doesn t display well

Tags: javascript, display

I'm trying to edit a .js file, but all the file is written on a very long single line, so it's very difficult to understand.

Here is a portion of the code :

```
,b[1]=128|(258048&f)>>>12,b[2]=128|(4032&f)>>>6,b[3]=128|63&f):f>2048?(b[0]=224|(61440&f)>>>12,b[1]=128|(4032&f)>>>6,b[2]=128|63&f):f>128?(b[0]=192|(1984&f)>>>6,b[1]=128|63&f):b[0]=f,this.parsedData=this.parsedData.concat(b)}this.parsedData.length!=this.data.length&&(this.parsedData.unshift(191),this.parsedData.unshift(187),this.parsedData.unshift(239))}function b(a,b){this.typeNumber=a,this.errorCorrectLevel=b,this.modules=null,this.moduleCount=0,this.dataCache=null,this.dataList=[]}function i(a,b){if(void 0==a.length)throw new Error(a.length+"/"+b);for(var c=0;c<a.length&&0==a[c];)c++;this.num=new Array(a.length-c+b);for(var d=0;d<a.length-c;d++)this.num[d]=a[d+c]}function j(a,b){this.totalCount=a,this.dataCount=b}function k(){this.buffer=[],this.length=0}function m(){return"undefined"!=typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D}function n(){var a=!1,b=navigator.userAgent;return/android/i.test(b)&&(a=!0,aMat=b.toString().match(
```

Is there a special editor or a special thing to do to have a better display ?

Thanks

Comment: Google "Google Chrome Pretty Print"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format

Comment: You may use http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: FYI: The file looks like a <something>.min.js, meaning that it is optimized for quick transfer over the net, therefore all the whitespace is stripped from the file which makes it smaller yet pretty much unreadable. As suggessted already i'd go with the pretty print chrome dev tools or jsbeautifier ;>